# Как вызвать метод дочернего класса, записанного в другом файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

У меня возникла проблема, если кто знает как ее решить и имеет время, помогите пожалуйста.

Я имею родительский класс, который находится в файле **tester.py**

```
l1 = [1, 1, 2]

class A:
   def __init__(self,l):
      self.l = l

   def qw(self):
        if l1[0] == 1:
           import qwe
           qwe.calculate()

f = A(l)
f.qw()
```

И также дочерний класс который находится в файле **qwe.py**

```
import tester

class B(tester.A):

   def calculate(self):
        print(self.l[0]+'Ok')
```

Я хочу использовать метод дочернего класса который находится в другом файле в родительском. Я пыталась сделать это так

```
              import qwe
            qwe.calculate()

f = A(l1)
f.qw()
```

Но у меня возникает ошибка и я не знаю почему, возможно, кто-то знает решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо объект класса B создать внутри класса A, тогда к нему можно будет применить метод calculate

**test.py**

```
l1 = [1, 1, 2]

class A:
   def __init__(self,l):
      self.l = l

   def qw(self):
        if l1[0] == 1:
           import test2
           qwe = test2.B(l1)
           qwe.calculate()

f = A(l1)
f.qw()
```

**test2.py**

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, _list):
        self._list = _list

    def calculate(self):
        print(f'{self._list[0]} Ok')
```

Comment: да, достаточно простая и изящная коррекция. Даже qwe переиспользовали, чтобы ничего не править, кроме одной доп.строки. Интерпретатор ругался на циклический импорт в коде из вопроса, но это, значит, не мешало тут.

Comment: @Сергей тут вопрос, что нужно автору, и для чего... Насколько я знаю, импорт где то внутри кода - не есть признак хорошего тона.

Comment: Да, но это почти наверняка учебный пример для отработки. А импорт такой для оптимизации пригодиться может, возможность-то даже в учебнике Чернышова указана, например, по условию импорт делать.

Comment: Как я поняла вы изменили название дочернего файла на  test2?
Извините пожалуйста за возможно глупые вопросы

Comment: @st040506 да, все верно, я поменял название

Comment: @st040506 и еще при создании экземпляра класса передал в него список(см предпоследнюю строку)

Comment: @CameL А в дочернем классе вы что-нибудь меняли? У меня просто ошибка и я не понимаю откуда она берется

Comment: @st040506 а вы не редактировали исходный вопрос? Видимо поменял, дополню ответ сейчас

Comment: @CameL Спасибо большое за помощь:)Теперь все работает

Comment: @st040506 пожалуйста:)

Comment: @CameL Простите еще раз что тревожу вы случайно не знаете как выйти из дочернего класса(который расположен в другом файле) обратно к родительскому и продолжить там работу. И дальше заходить снова возможно в этот самый возможно в другой файл с дочерним классом?

Comment: @st040506 я не совсем понимаю что значит выйти из класса. Вы создаете экземпляр этого класса, вы в него не входите. Создайте новый вопрос, с примером, я или другие участники форума постараются ответить.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

**tester.py**

```
from qwe import B
        

class A:
    def __init__(self, _list, value):
        self._list = _list
        self.value = value
        
        self.b = B(self._list)

    def qw(self):
        if self._list[0] == self.value:
            self.b.calculate()            


my_list = [1, 1, 2]    
    
a = A(my_list, 1)
a.qw()
```

**qwe.py**

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, _list):
        self._list = _list
        
    def calculate(self):
        print(f'{self._list[0]} Ok')
```

Comment: как я понимаю, идея автора была импорт дочернего класса из другого файла провести только при выполнении условия в родительском классе. У вас же больше нет этого условия, и всё упрощается. Вообще идея не сработает?